# Nested SEARCH and IF grid

Tags: excel, search, if-statement

Column A lists the categories for individual products.  Each product will have between 1 to 14 categories.  The goal is to split all categories into separate cells (Columns B through O), to become easier to sort.

I've created formulas for columns B through O, to SEARCH for hyphens "-" and separate each category into its own column.  Here's what the output should look like (except for the bottom row):

```
A                       B       C       D       E       F       G       ...     O
Categories              Cat 1   Cat 2   Cat 3   Cat 4   Cat 5   Cat 6   ...     Cat 14

UX                      UX      
CFT-WET                 CFT     WET 
WEM-US-CFT              WEM     US      CFT
NC-US-CFT               NC      US      CFT
TP-OB-SB-WEB            TP      OB      SB      WEB
DB-B-FC                 DB      B       FC
P-TP-SB-CP-DT           P       TP      SB      CP      DT
DP-S-OB-WB-SB-FC DP     S       OB      WB      SB      FC
P-TP-SB-CP-WEB-WS-S-TP-OB-C-CT-G-FC-MCB
```

I initially built these formulas:

```
Col B:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5)),$A5,search("-",$A5))
Col C:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,sum(search("-",$A5)+1))),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5),1),sum(search("-",$A5,sum(search("-",$A5)+1)),-search("-",$A5),-1)))
Col D:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1),-1)))
Col E:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1),-1)))
Col F:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col G:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col H:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col I:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col J:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col K:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col L:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col M:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col N:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
Col O:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)),"",mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1),-1)))
```

...but these fail to recognize the final category for each row.  Col B's formula has no problems, so I began to edit the formulas in Columns C to O:

```
Col C:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,sum(search("-",$A5)+1))),if($B5<>"",right($A5,sum(len($A5),-search("-",$A5))),""),mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5),1),sum(search("-",$A5,sum(search("-",$A5)+1)),-search("-",$A5),-1)))
Col D:  =if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1)),if($C5<>"",if(iserror(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)),"",right($A5,len(sum($A5,-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1))))),""),mid($A5,sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1),1),sum(search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1)+1),-search("-",$A5,search("-",$A5)+1),-1)))
```

It appears this solution will work for all situations except when Column A has only one category.  When that happens, a #VALUE! error will populate all columns to the right of Col B.  How do I solve this?

For now, I'm stuck with this:

```
A                       B       C       D       E       F       G       ...     O
Categories              Cat 1   Cat 2   Cat 3   Cat 4   Cat 5   Cat 6   ...     Cat 14

UX                      UX      #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! ...     #VALUE! 
CFT-WET                 CFT     WET 
WEM-US-CFT              WEM     US      CFT
NC-US-CFT               NC      US      CFT
TP-OB-SB-WEB            TP      OB      SB      WEB
DB-B-FC                 DB      B       FC
P-TP-SB-CP-DT           P       TP      SB      CP      DT
DP-S-OB-WB-SB-FC DP     S       OB      WB      SB      FC
P-TP-SB-CP-WEB-WS-S-TP-OB-C-CT-G-FC-MCB
```

Comment: is there a reason you can't use Text to Columns (with a delimiter of "-")?

Comment: I'm not familiar, can you share that tip for me?

Comment: it's about 30 seconds later, and i found that feature.  wow!!  what a breeze.  i'll try your formula below as well, but this appears to work well

Comment: Any suggestions for where to work on 500,000 records (rows of data)?  Seems excel and google sheets are completely hamstrung by the weight of it.  It's currently split into several files, but needs to merge.

Comment: Try saving as csv then Data / Get external Data / from Text / Delimited / "-" ....should be much faster

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would use

I'm assuming row 1 of your spreadsheet contains "Cat 1", "Cat 2" etc. This formula relies on there being a space between "Cat" and the category number. I'm also assuming column A contains the concatenated string.

Note this requires that no category will ever have the character `:` in it. If there is a risk of this, you can modify the ":" to become any other character in the formula below (the below example goes in cell B2

```
=IF(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"-",""))+1>=VALUE(MID(B$1,SEARCH(" ",B$1)+1,100)), MID("-"&$A2&"-",SEARCH(":",SUBSTITUTE("-"&$A2&"-","-",":",VALUE(MID(B$1,SEARCH(" ",B$1)+1,100))))+1,SEARCH(":",SUBSTITUTE("-"&$A2&"-","-",":",VALUE(MID(B$1,SEARCH(" ",B$1)+1,100)+1)))-SEARCH(":",SUBSTITUTE("-"&$A2&"-","-",":",VALUE(MID(B$1,SEARCH(" ",B$1)+1,100))))-1),"")
```

A brief explanation: the last optional term of SUBSTITUTE is instance_num, which means you can change the nth instance of "-" to ":" and then search on that. This keeps the formula pretty simple. I've also added a "-" before and after the string in the formula to avoid having to use any if statements (there will always be a trailing and preceding "-")